# ASA 5506-X as NAT only

Tags: cisco-asa, nat

We have a spare ASA 5506-X that we want to use as a NAT.
It will be placed between a VLAN and a machine network. 
Is it possible to setup the device using only the wizard for this functionality. (I have installed the programming interface and I'm trying to setup the system using the setup wizard).
I only want to use it as NAT and not as a Firewall, so everything should just pass through.
Is it enough to set the outside to security 100 and then just use the NAT tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

Be aware that, by default, ASA permits traffic from higher security-level interface to lower security-level interface. Therefore you must set the security level for both interfaces correctly for traffic to pass through.

Comment: So would setting both outside and inside =100 be sufficient to ensure all traffic passes through?

Comment: @DavyGravy You should not set the same security level for inside and outside interfaces. In case you do that, you would need an additional command 'same-security-traffic permit inter-interface'

Comment: Thanks for that, does that also apply for 2 different subnets assigned to inside network objects?